# Can a cut mint root grow into a plant?

Tags: mint

A few days ago, a friend gave me a mint plant submerged in water. It was my first time so I researched carefully, and took cuttings and planted them in pots. A few days later, they shriveled up and died.

Desperate, I snipped off a medium sized root from the main plant and put it in a pot. The root about 4cm, was yellowish white, and had a small 2cm stem that was woody. Considering that the stem was white and woody, will it grow back to create a lush mint plant?

Comment: Did you include photosynthetic growth with your roots that you cut off?  If not I doubt those roots will create vegetative growth. Mint is a pretty gnarly plant but really need to know the species, environment to help you further.  Please send a picture or two or three.  Few plants grow from roots only.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Various mint species have stolons, so in general they should be able to growth from roots.

Now you should try to identify which mint you got. There are many species, some likes dry places, and some likes the very wet places. Because you received it submerged, I would tend on later one, but the most common mints like dry places (people likes them because they forgive you if you forget to water them regularly).  Without good identification, I would keep soil mostly dry.